# Why this answer passes Leetcode Q41

Tags: python, algorithm

Question here: https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/description/

> Your algorithm should run in O(n) time and uses constant extra space.

I have a very naive solution that passes, since the question is marked as hard and most people's solution in discussion is much more complicated.

```
def firstMissingPositive(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        if nums == []:
            return 1
        for i in range(1, max(nums)+2):
            if i not in nums:
                return i
```

find `max` uses O(n), since loop would stop once found the missing positive it would be O(n). `range` in py3 returns an iterable, every loop of the for statement produces the next number on the fly. So the time complexity should be O(n)

space complexity is O(1) since only `i` is created

I suppose the OJ only checks the correctness but not the space/ time complexity. However I cant see how this solution is wrong. Could anyone point it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit loop `for i in range(1, max(nums)+2):` with nested implicit loop `if i not in nums:` is not `O(n)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have two loops inside each other.  You have a iterating from `1` to `max(nums)+2` and inside that `if i not in nums:` which iterates over `nums`. so your complexity will be something like `O(n^2)`.